# The payment was refused: Risk Score 100+

Tags: adyen

While testing the integration of an Adyen library/SDK the payment can be declined even when using the [Adyen Test cards](https://docs.adyen.com/development-resources/testing/test-card-numbers).
The setup and code are correct, however the risk score is 100 or more.

Is it possible to control/disable the Risk Rules so the integration can be tested without being affected by the risk factors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 options to disable the Risk Rules. It is **recommended to do this only when necessary** (ie for example at the start of implementing the integration with Adyen, but then make sure to test with the Risk Rules enabled)

#### Skip risk rules

During your development/testing you can instruct the platform to skip risk checks (https://docs.adyen.com/risk-management/skip-risk-rules), by adding `riskdata.skipRisk` as additionalData of the payment request, for example when you initiate the `session`

```
amount: { 
   currency: "EUR", 
   value: 1000
},
merchantAccount: "xyz",
reference: "abc",
additionalData: {
   "riskdata.skipRisk": true
}
```

The transaction will always have a Risk Score equals to 0.

#### Disable Risk Profile

Access the Risk Settings (if you are a Risk Admin) and turn off completely the Risk system (https://docs.adyen.com/risk-management/configure-risk-settings)